# Help with trigger on lead

Tags: apex

I want to write a trigger on lead. when new record come it match email id with old record. if email match it update the old record otherwise insert a new lead.
please help me...
i am new in development. please help with code.

Comment: To get help with code you must provide atleast some of the code part whatever you have tried so far. You must ask specific questions not the generalized problem statement so that it would be easier for us to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to prevent duplicate records from being created on the basis of email Id. Assuming the API name of the email field is "**email**", You can do something like this:

```
trigger preventDuplication on Lead (before insert,before update)
{
    Map<String, Lead> leadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
    for (Lead l : System.Trigger.new)
    {
        if ((l.email != null) && (System.Trigger.isInsert || (l.email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).email)))
        {
            if (leadMap.containsKey(l.email))
            {
                l.email.addError('Another Lead has same email. Please use a different email Id');
            }
            else
            {
                leadMap.put(l.email, l);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Lead ld : [SELECT email FROM Lead WHERE email IN :leadMap.KeySet()])
    {
        leadMap.get(ld.email).email.addError('Another Lead has same email. Please use a different email Id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved if it meets your requirement.

Comment: Hi heisenberg,i  also agree with you but i have to import these lead from campaign member. if it add error at in between the importing than all importing will fail. this is the problem.

Comment: Sorry I dont' understand "import from Camapign members". As far as I know, Campaign members is a junction object between "Lead and Campaign" OR "Contact and Campaign". Before you create a CampaignMember, the Lead must be created. Isn't it?

Comment: Ok no issues. 
Please fix previous error.
If email match with old lead than it update old lead record. if Email not match than create a new lead record.

Comment: There is no error. Can you explain what error you talking about?

Comment: The trigger is in accordance with your requirement. Dont worry about that.

Comment: In this code it create a error if a Email already exists.
but according to my requirment old record should be updated if Email already exists.

Comment: See this:   l.email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).email ---- > If you dont change the email of old record, the record will save successfully.

Comment: Anytime. Enjoy.

Comment: But as per the requirment mentioned by @ParteekGoyal the lead should update if lead with same email exits. i am sorry but i didnt find that functionality in this code

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand why cannot you see that. It throws error, when u insert a lead with email  already present in the database OR you are trying to update a lead with email already present in database. And it doesn't throw error if a email is not. The trigger is using email to determine duplicate records. You should simply copy paste the same and try it in your org @snehakem. Let me know if the results are not expected.

Comment: l.email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).email --> This tells the trigger to throw error ONLY when you change the email of existing record. Same email will still update because it wont satisfy the condition.

Comment: When you read the question you will see  "if email match it update the old record ". Where are you updating the record?

Comment: @ParteekGoyal -  "if email match it update the old record" --> update the old record with what? Kindly clarify. If that is the case, a little tweak in the code would do the job. Thanks snehakem.

Comment: if email match then it should update old record data with new record data.